# What is the most efficient way of determining if a two dimensional Ruby Array is empty?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given an array of empty arrays in Ruby:

```
a = [ [], [], [], [], [] ]
```

You can determine if all sub-arrays arrays are empty using:

```
a.uniq.length == 1                # Ignoring the flaw where sub-arrays are identical
a.index { |item| item != [] }.nil?
a.flatten.empty?
a.all? { |item| item.empty? }           # Fastest of the four
```

The approaches above are listed from slowest to fastest. Is there a faster way than using `a.all? { |x| x.empty? }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be surprised when you find a faster way as:

```
array.all? { |element| element.empty? }
```

What makes kind of sense if we look how they work. This look at every element if it is empty, but stops as soon as there is an non-empty element. That means it takes a *maximum of `n` steps* and doesn't change the array.

Whereas most of the other examples change the array. That means they need to allocate memory and copy data. If you manipulate the data first than you will need *exactly `n` steps* plus the checks after that.

Comment: Yep, I'm wondering if there is a clever way to do this faster than O(n) in the worst case.

Comment: I would argue that if you have an array and need to check if any of the subarrays is not empty, then there no faster way than `O(n)`, because you must check all subarray in the worst case.

Comment: I don't see either how it could be faster. @spickermann : Minor nitpick : the other examples don't change the array. They create a new one, which takes time and memory.